# dnspython Set the DNS server for DDNS updates?

Tags: dns, updates, dnspython

In dnspython you can set the server for queries via dns.resolver.nameservers.

Is there an equivalent statement to set the dns server for DDNS updates via dnspython?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.

Of course its set when you send it...

response = dns.query.tcp(update, server, timeout = 10)

Apologies.